# std::future::wait_for is causing a deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, mutex

I use in my code [`std::promise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) and [`std::shared_future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future) (which is a multiple waiting threads version of [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)) for asynchronous execution, and I found a case where it never come back (deadlock) when calling this function with 100 ms (or any other time duration).

This is the piece of code (from my class) that suppose to block the thread until someone sets the value of the `std::promise` related to this `std::shared_future`:

```
    bool wait_until_ready(unsigned int msec)
    {
        if (_ready)
            return true;

        std::chrono::milliseconds span(msec);
        std::future_status fstat;
        fstat = _shared_fut.wait_for(span);
        if (fstat == std::future_status::ready)
        {
                _shared_fut.get();
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void init()
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lck(_mutex);
            _promise = promise<bool>();
            _shared_fut = _promise.get_future().share();
            _ready = false;
        }

    void set_ready()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(_mutex);
        if (!_ready)
        {
            _ready = true;
            _promise.set_value(true);
        }
    }
```

The call to `wait_for()` consistently causing a deadlock (no exception is being thrown).

Has anyone experienced this kind of behavior from `std::future` before?

Comment: Two comments: (1) Show more code, please. Please read how to create a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (2) Your function `wait_until_ready` does not do what the name of the function suggests it does.

Comment: Just a bit about terminology: this doesn't look like a deadlock. A deadlock occurs when two threads are fighting for the same resources, neither is willing to give up what it has, and each wants what the other has. `wait_for` not returning is probably the result of an incorrect value somewhere, or possibly a corrupted data structure. Impossible to say without more code.

Comment: Check if `_shared_fut.valid()` is true before your wait.